# Incorrect SQL syntax with date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

I have a vb6 application with a sql server backend.Here's my following code:

```
 cn.Execute "insert into abschart ([t_leave],[cu_month],[last_month],[last_year_month]) SELECT * FROM" _
 & "(SELECT     no_d_sick,period_e,'sick' as t_leave from foxmil...transac)" _
 & "AS n PIVOT (sum(no_d_sick) FOR period_e IN (['" & txtend & "'],['" & lmon & "'],['" & lymon & "'])) AS pvt Union SELECT * FROM" _
 & "(SELECT     no_d_abs,period_e,'Absence' as t_leave from foxmil...transac)" _
 & "AS n PIVOT (sum(no_d_abs) FOR period_e IN (['" & txtend & "'],['" & lmon & "'],['" & lymon & "'])) AS pvt".
```

I am getting Incorrect syntax error for the "txtend".The txtend is of date type.

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near 'date'"? There is no 'date' in your query, maybe txtend has the value 'date'? What do you get when you print the statement? 
You also need to add some spaces at the end (or at the beginning) of each line.

Comment: If you cannot debug your huge piece of code - then start writing it iteratively, step by step so you could know when exactly you made mistake

Comment: Can you post an example of the SQL string as it is compiled? (e.g. with txtend, lmon, and lymon evaluated)

Comment: when i replace the (['" & txtend & "']) with ([20-Nov-11]) it work,but I need to make it read in the txtend textbox value.

Comment: Should the values be surrounded in `[]`? I thought that was for "quoting" names only.

Answer (score 2):

It's those extra quotes you've got in your substitution code. You said that `([20-Nov-11])` worked, but `(['" & txtend & "'])` didn't, but notice that that second example will produce `(['20-Nov-11'])`.

---

I agree with others that it would be better to avoid string concatenation (although I don't think you can for a pivot clause).

Also, it would be better to use an unambiguous date format, such as `YYYYMMDD`, e.g. today would be `20111129`.

Comment: Thanks damien. I'll try and let you know.